# In Python query MongoDB collection excluding the results from another collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I have a `collection1`:

```
field11 | field12
a1 | text1
b1 | text2
c1 | text3
...
```

And another `collection2`:

```
field21 | field22
a1 | a2
c1 | c2
f1 | a2
...
```

What I need is to query `collection1` getting all results where field11 doesn't exist in the `field21` of `collection2`.

The way i do it now is like this:

```
excluded = []
cursor2 = collection2.find({'field22': 'a2'})
for doc in cursor2:
    excluded.append(doc['field21'])
cursor1 = collection1.find({'field11': {'$nin': excluded}})
```

So basically i assemble a list of field values from the second collection based on certain search criteria and then run another query against first collection where i specify that i need results where `field11` IS NOT IN the assembled list of values.

It works. No problem. But I'm getting worried because `collection2` keeps growing and this `excluded` list keep growing. I have irrational fear of hitting the python list limits:) but also I am worried that maybe the bigger the list the slower the query runs to find results not in it...

I am new to MongoDB and figured this way myself, so I am not sure if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: What size are you talking about? How big is 'big'?

Comment: @LutzHorn For now `excluded` grows by around 50 items daily. but it is supposed to be a self sustainable system in a very long run (months..years..). It's running for couple of days now and has around 600 elements in the list. I get that it's peanuts but i'm worried for later:(

Comment: You will likely get an answer if you add sample documents from your collections with the expected output.